# CollectionFS getting url of image file

Tags: meteor, collectionfs

Hi am using CollectionFS to upload and store images.

Uploading and storing the file is successful. I can retrieve file object from publication. But am unable to get URL for file. I need url for `img` tag

Following is how I declared collections.

```
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
    stores: [new FS.Store.GridFS("images")]
});
```

In browser console following code returns FS.File object

```
NewsImages.find().fetch()[0]
FS.File {createdByTransform: true, _id: "3kqLZRdLD33dKir2M", original: Object, chunkSize: 2097152, chunkCount: 0…}
```

But url is returning null.

```
NewsImages.find().fetch()[0].url()
null
```

Is there any extra work needed to generate URL?

**More Details**

I am using following allow rules.

```
NewsImages.allow({
    //more others
    download: function(){
        if(Meteor.userId()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

I am getting following exception.

```
Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId in publish functions.
```

I replaced `Meteor.userId()` with `this.userId` but `this.userId` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Use a callback on saving the image and then put the image id into another 
collection. Rough pseudo code...

```
Images.insert(yourFsFile, function (error, fileObj) {
    if (error) {
      // cry!
    }

    _.extend(yourItem, {imageId: fileObj._id});

    Meteor.call('otherCollectioInsert', yourItem, function(error, result) {
      if (error) {
        // cry again!
      }
      // should have saved the image id so you can use the url
      // http://www.you.com/cfs/files/images/the_id_you_saved
    });
  });
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Tried specified method. While retrieving image using URL am getting 403 forbidden message. Should I add any security rules?

Comment: I think you may need a timeout or make it reactive while the image is loaded into the store.